# Ruby code in logstash failing with _rubyexception

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, logstash

I would like to get help with the code in ruby filter.

logstash version is 5.0.0 alpha4.

I am testing the code in ruby filter as below but I am getting _rubyexception.

```
  ruby {
    code => "
      event['newfield'] = 'test'
    "
  }
```

ruby filter is defined inside filter { }.
The logstash.log shows as below,

```
:timestamp=>"2016-08-03T15:26:47.291000+0900", :message=>"Ruby exception occurred: undefined method[]=' for 2016-08-03T06:26:46.829Z test %{message}:LogStash::Event", :level=>:error}
```

I cant find the reason why ruby filter is unable to use event object.
I appreciate if I could get some help to cope this issue.

Thanks,
Yu

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a new event API in Logstash 5.0.0 and now you need to set fields on the event as follows:

```
  ruby {
    code => "
      event.set('newfield', 'test')
    "
  }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For get the value from field name:

```
ruby {
 code => "
 value = (event.get('field_name'))
    "
}
```